# apache java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache, exception

I am trying to create application which uses *org.apache.commons.httpclient* package. For this purpose I downloaded *org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar* and located it in \libraries folder inside my project. Then added it as a library through *Project Structure*. However, when I run my program it throws ***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory*** on the line 
`HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`
Will be very grateful for any kind of advise.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.io.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Crawler {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String key = "5485fd7342c54e2ef3640cc94f71056b";
        String secret = "1d4cb8b3br1d3x4b";
        String methodGetFrob = "flickr.auth.getFrob";
        String sig = secret + "api_key" + key + "method" + methodGetFrob;
        String signature = DigestUtils.md5Hex(sig);
        String request = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=" + methodGetFrob + "&api_key=" + key + "&api_sig=" + signature;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(request);
        int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What jars you are having in your classpath?

Comment: Are you just using org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar jar in your classpath?

Comment: @asg I am using intelliJ Idea. As I said, I just added this jar as a library. Need to do something else?

Comment: You might have different jar for DigestUtils class.

Comment: On IntellJ use (Ctrl + N) to find out DigestUtils class is resolved from which class.

Comment: @asg jar for DigestUtils was also included. I did not mention it, because the exception is connected to particular line of code, It is about HttpClient

Comment: Okay.. what I am interested in is the jars and their versions you are using in your code so that your scenario can be reproduced.

Comment: @asg here they are 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscodecjar.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscodecjar.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added three jars to the classpath and code worked perfectly fine for me.

```
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

Please let me know if you run into any issues.